# What should I use between MS SQL Server and MongoDb?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, asp.net-core, nosql

I am currently working on a project in ASP.Net Core which will have a large number of user in the future. Also, the application is being made through Agile Process, so that I have to be prepared for many changes and up-gradations in the future. 
First, I was planning to use a MS SQL Server Database but recently I have seen that how awesome features MongoDb is providing especially for a developer. But, I have a confusion that using I MongoDb database will slow down my application when it become widely used by the people.
So, I am here to get some suggestions on choosing the database for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is one of the most popular document stores available both as a fully managed cloud service and for deployment on the self-managed infrastructure but it is Document store DB and SQL Server is Relational DBMS.

Performance highly depends on your requirement and design.

[System Properties Comparison Microsoft SQL Server vs. MongoDB](https://db-engines.com/en/system/Microsoft+SQL+Server%3BMongoDB)

[MongoDB vs SQL Server 2016 Performance](http://memilavi.com/2018/08/15/mongodb-vs-sql-server-2016-performance/)